# retrieve info from a method on another file

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to call rtnval from newhello.java from HelloWorld.java

These are the errors i get

Error:(9, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method newhello()
  location: class HelloWorld

Error:(10, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method newval()
  location: class HelloWorld

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Test");
        int fnum1 = addition(8,2);
        System.out.println(fnum1);
        int fnum2 = subtract(2,8);
        System.out.println(fnum2);
        newhello newval = newhello();
        System.out.println(newval());
    }
    public static int addition (int num1, int num2){
        int total;
        total = num1 + num2;
        return total;
    }
    public static int subtract (int num1, int num2){
        int total;
        total = num1 - num2;
        return total;
    }
}
public class newhello extends HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(rtnval());
    }
    public static String rtnval (){
        String msg;
        msg = "Test";
        return msg;
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that i had to call the instance for it then use it that way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `newhello();` refers to a `newhello()` method in the current class.
It doesn't exist.

> I was under the impression that i had to call the instance for it then
>   use it that way??

In fact, you don't need to create a `newhello` instance as `rtnval` is a static method.
So just do it : `newhello.rtnval();`

Note that in Java, class names should start with an uppercase and using camelcase.
For example, according to naming conventions, developers expect to an instance method invocation on a variable :

```
newhello.rtnval();
```

While here we expect to a `static` method invocation :

```
Newhello.rtnval();
```

So `NewHello` is a better class name.

Comment: Your solution was the fix. I also properly renamed it to NewHello. i was able to call it no issues with System.out.println(NewHello.rtnval());

Question. in what circumstances would a "non-static" would come to play?

Answer (score 0):

You made it a static method so just call:

newhello.rtnval();

But you've also made a mistake when creating an instance. Instead of this:

```
newhello newval = newhello();
```

You need to use the keyword new to make a new instance!

```
newhello newval = new newhello();
```

The thing is... I see you don't understand Java the best. You have 2 main methods, didn't use the new keyword and so on... Before trying to make your own program watch some tutorials. I've been stuck in the same thing when i was learning. Not wanting to look at tutorials. I will link you some great tutorials for you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28

Good luck!